# Web API controller does not respect CORS origin

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, cors

I recently implemented cors into my Web API controller. I am calling the web api located on domain1 from a client on domain2.

For the origin, I specified a bogus url. To my understanding, only calls from this url will be accepted. Is this correct?

So only calls from

```
 http://notgoingtowork.com
```

will be able to call the controller and return data

Here is my controller (domain1)

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://notgoingtowork.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public int Get()
    {
       return 1
    }
}
```

And then on my other domain, the ajax call (domain2)

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://domain1/api/Test/Get", 
            method: "GET", 
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data){alert("it worked");},
            error: function (error) { alert("Did not work"); }
        })
```

However, the request still is successful and is returning data. As the client is not on 'http://notgoingtowork.com', how is it able to successfully do this? What am I missing?

I am doing this on IE11. This works fine on chrome.

**EDIT:**
Here is the WebApiConfig.cs file
It is pretty generic. I just added the Cors part

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify the value of `data` too? Not just the `alert()`

Comment: Yes. All that data gets returned

Comment: Do you have anything in your `Startup.cs` enabling cors?

Comment: Is there anything in your IE 11 Console after the Ajax call is made? Also, is your client actually on a different domain?

Comment: I added the web api config part of it. Nothing shows up in the IE console. Besides the standard 200 OK result

Comment: Is there an `Origin` HTTP header in your Http Request?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything explicitly labeled Origin...through there is a label called Referer which holds the url of the client making the call

Comment: And the host and client are not on the same domain - it's not just faked? The XmlHttpRequest object generates the request and determines if it's a CORS request, so you can't just fake it out.

Comment: Correct they are not on the same domain. It's not faked. So testing in Chrome produces the desired result in that it cannot access the controller. So it looks like it might be some sort of IE setting...maybe

Answer (score 1):

there is a setting "Access data sources across domains" in IE 11, make sure if it is disabled:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what that setting does to the API calls ?

Comment: @PawOrmstrupMadsen it basically disallows accessing data sources across domains what is a secure and recommended setting. You should enable this only if know what you are doing.

Comment: I have a setup with an angular 6 webapp and an aspnet core api with correct cors settings, on 2 different urls. The api is actually using windows auth to generate a jwt token which the angular app is using to access data, using that jwt token, but if the pc has this setting enabled, IE 11 keeps asking for credentials but it does not work typing in correct ones. Chrome seems to not use that "internet option" so it works fine. If i set it to prompt or disabled IE 11 works fine again. So i was wondering what that setting does to the xhr call?

Comment: It seems to mess with request headers? Im am not responsible for that setting, its a big organization who has it enabled in a GPO. We are trying to get them to disable it.